# How can I find ibus-googlepinyin?

Tags: 14.04, ibus, input-method

I have installed googlepinyin input in ubuntu 14.04 LTS. But I can't find the googlepinyin input in the IBus Preference setting as following:

I have selected an input method in the settings and I also can't find googlepin input.

I am very curious that I have installed it but can't find it in ibus. What should I do?

By the way, I install the input using the `apt-get` command.

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: Did you relogin? Also, if you are on Ubuntu, you shouldn't bother about the IBus Preferences, but instead handle your input sources via _System Settings -> Text Entry_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ibus-googlepinyin` is based on `libgooglepinyin` which is not updated [anymore](https://code.google.com/p/libgooglepinyin/). Instead `fcitx-googlepinyin` is a better choice.

To install `googlepinyin`, Open a terminal and type the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install fcitx-googlepinyin
im-config
```

In the windows, click "OK", then "Yes", and select `fcitx`. Click "OK" to confirm and then "OK" to exit.

Now log-out and log-in back. You should see a Keyboard on the top right corner.

[image]

Click on it and then select "Configure Current Input Method".

Press `+` to add a new language. De-select “Only show current language”. Type in Google-Pinyin. Press "OK". Close the window.

Now, you can click on the keyboard, go to "input methods" and select google pinyin.

[image]

If you want other options, you can also use `libpinyin` or `sunpinyinas`, both supported by `ibus` and `fcitx` described [here](http://www.pinyinjoe.com/linux/ubuntu-10-chinese-input-pinyin-chewing.htm)

Comment: Is _ibus-googlepinyin_, which is available in 14.04, broken? In any case I think you should explain why your answer makes use of fcitx.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson thanks for pointing out, edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Installed Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 on Intel Core, 64bits, i3-7100, with Keyboard Chinese, English (UK) and English (US) and the selected language is English UK, Chinese China, Hong Kong and Taiwan, respectively.

The **Keyboard input method system** in **Language Support** must be **fcitx** NOT **iBus**.

Run Application "Terminal".

```
sudo apt-get install fcitx-googlepinyin im-config
```

logout and login Ubuntu or Debian again. click in tool bar on menu ConfigureFcitx. press Add,scroll down the list and select the Googlepinyin (Chinese China). Exit window.

DONE!!